# Laravel 5.2 - convert json key values to array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-5

I have the following json object:

```
{"keywords": "foo", "industries":"1,37","contractTypes":"1"}
```

How can i convert the following key values in to an array as follows:

```
{"keywords": "foo", "industries": ["1", "37"], "contractTypes": ["1"]}
```

So basically I want to loop through the object and if property `industries` and `contractTypes` exist and not empty then convert the values into array.

Comment: Any reason why when you convert it, value for `keywords` is not in an array but value for `contractTypes` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Define the list of properties that you want to convert to arrays

  ```
  $array_properties = ['industries', 'contractTypes'];
  ```
- decode the JSON

  ```
  $object = json_decode($json);
  ```
- Iterate the properties you defined and convert each one to an array if it exists on the object.

  ```
  foreach ($array_properties as $property) {
      if (isset($object->$property)) {
          $object->$property = explode(',', $object->$property);
      }
  }
  ```
- You can re-encode the object to JSON afterward if you need to.

  ```
  $object = json_encode($object);
  ```
- get money